# Zend Dojo FilteringSelect from joined tables How can this be done with Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, doctrine

I have a number of FilteringSelect elements within my Zend Framework application that are working fine but they are based on simple queries.

I now need to create a FilteringSelect that will allow me to select the id of one table while displaying the text of field in a related table, i.e. I have two tables groomservices and groomprocedures which are related (i.e. groomprocedures.groomProceduresID has many groomservices.procedure).
The form I'm trying to create is for an appointments table which has many groomservices.groomServicesID values. I want the user to be able to see the name of the procedure while saving the value of the groomservices.groomServicesID using the FilteringSelect.

So far I've not been able to do this in that my FilteringSelect displays nothing, I'm sure this can be done just that the fault is with my inexperience with Zend,Doctrine and Dojo

I'm not sure if my problem is with my autocomplete action(including the query) or with the FilteringSelect element.

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong in the code sections below, I need to get this working.

My autocomplete action within my controller

```
public function gserviceAction()
{
// disable layout and view rendering
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);

    // get a list of all grooming services IDs and related procedures
 $qry= Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('g.groomServicesID,p.groomProcedure')
    ->from('PetManager_Model_Groomservices g')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures p');
    $result=$qry->fetchArray();

   //generate and return JSON string 
   $data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('g.groomServicesID',$result);
   echo $data->toJson();
}
```

My FilteringSelect element code

```
  // Create a autocomplete select input for the service
    $gservice = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('gapmtService');
    $gservice->setLabel('Proceedure');
        $gservice->setOptions(array(
          'autocomplete' => true,
          'storeID'   => 'gserviceStore',
          'storeType' => 'dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore',
         'storeParams' => array('url' => "/groomappointments/appointment/gservice"),
         'dijitParams' => array('searchAttr' => 'groomProcedure')))
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
          ->addFilter('HTMLEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StringToLower')        
          ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

Many thanks in advance,

Graham

P.S. orgot to mention I tried the following query in mysql and I gave me what I'm looking for I believe the Doctine query evaluates to the same.

```
select groomservices.groomservicesID,groomprocedures.groomprocedure from groomprocedures left join groomservices on groomprocedures.groomproceduresID =groomservices.groomProcedure
```

But I'm not sure if I formatted the query correctly in Doctrine.

EDIT in relation to the flammon's comments

Ok I've set the code to the following but I'm still not getting anything to display.

```
public function gserviceAction()
{
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContexts(array(
    'gservice' => 'json' 
));

// get a list of all grooming services IDs and related procedures
 $qry= Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->select('g.groomServicesID AS id,p.groomprocedure AS name')
    ->from('PetManager_Model_Groomservices g')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures p');

    $this->view->model = (object) array();
    $this->view->model->identifier = 'id';
    $this->view->model->label = 'name';
    $this->view->model->items = array();

    $tableRows = $this->dbTable->fetchAll($qry);

    foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
            $this->view->model->items[] = $row->toArray();
            }

  }
```

I'm sure the fault lies with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem with the data that you're putting in the ItemFileReadStore.

Here are a few pointers.

Consider extending Zend_Rest_Controller for your services. It'll be easier to manage your contexts and your views. You'll be able to do something like this:

```
public function init()
{
    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContexts(array(
        'gservice' => 'json'
    ));
}
```

And it will eliminate the need for the following in each of you service actions.

```
// disable layout and view rendering
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
```

You'll need to either pass the format parameter or use the following plugin to help with the context switch. Passing the format parameter is simpler but it pollutes the url with ?format=json. Here's the [Zend documentation on AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html).

Here's a plugin that you can use if you don't want to pass the format parameter.

```
class Application_Plugin_AcceptHandler extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {

        if (!$request instanceof Zend_Controller_Request_Http) {
            return;
        }

        $header = $request->getHeader('Accept');

        switch (true) {
        case (strstr($header, 'application/json')):
            Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log('Setting format to json', Zend_Log::INFO);
            $request->setParam('format', 'json');
            break;
        case (strstr($header, 'application/xml')
            && (!strstr($header, 'html'))):
            Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log('Setting format to xml', Zend_Log::INFO);
            $request->setParam('format', 'xml');
            break;
        default:
            Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log('Setting format to html', Zend_Log::INFO);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller, instead of echoing the data, create view variables that dojo expects. See this [document](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/simple.html#quickstart-data-usingdatastores-simple) for the format.

```
$this->view->model = (object) array();
$this->view->model->identifier = 'id';
$this->view->model->label = 'name';
$this->view->model->items = array();
```

In your controller, fetch your table rows:

```
$tableRows = $this->dbTable->fetchAll($select);
```

or, if you've put model code in a function, it might look more like:

```
$tableRows = $this->dbTable->fetchGroomProcedures();
```

Put your row data in the model->items[] array:

```
foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
    $this->view->model->items[] = $row->toArray();
}
```

Create a view, view/scripts/appointment/gservice.json.phtml and in it put

```
Zend_Json::encode($this->model)
```

Use Firebug to see what is returned from your service.

Comment: @flammon Thank you for your input it is extensive, however as I'm new to Zend and Dojo I'm a bit confused. From what your explaining it looks like I will have to have a different view rendered inside my form to display the FilteringSelect results when I want to create an appointment is this correct?

Comment: @Graham Yes, that's right. The data for the FilteringSelect is loaded from a different view. When you specify 'storeParams' => array('url' => "/groomappointments/appointment/gservice"), the gservice action will prepare that view's data. One more thing, you'll probably want to alias the fields in your query to id and name. ex. g.groomServicesID AS id, p.groomProcedure AS name to make it work with the example.

Comment: @flammon I think I did what you described but I'm still getting Error Unable to load /groomappointments/appointment/gservice status:500  1234 out of range 505 and 646 out of range 103 in firebug

Comment: I suspect that the context isn't switching and causing the 500. You can test this by creating view/scripts/appointment/gservice.phtml with the same content as gservice.json.phtml. I've updated the answer to include more information about the AjaxContext helper. You'll either need to pass ?format=json or use the plugin provided.

Comment: @flammon I checked my error logs in Apache and it has reported PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Groomappointments_AppointmentController::$dbTable in C:\\..\\..\\application\\modules\\groomappointments\\controllers\\AppointmentController.php on line 43, referer: http://petmanager/groomappointments/appointment/create
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\\WebDocs\\petmanager\\application\\modules\\groomappointments\\controllers\\AppointmentController.php on line 43, referer: http://petmanager/groomappointments/appointment/create

Comment: @flammon no room let to say it in the last comment but thanks for your help so far its appreciated.

Comment: @Graham You'll need to replace the `$tableRows = $this->dbTable->fetchAll($qry)` with the Doctrine specific code. I just put `$this->dbTable`... in my sample because I typically make my `Zend_Db_Table` available to my controller. In the controller `init()`, I'll have something like `$this->dbTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Groomservices();` I haven't done Doctrine but I suspect that it's similar.

Comment: @flammon I thought this might be the case I'm trying to see if I can find the equivalent code for Doctrine but not having that much luck. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @Graham It might be as simple as replacing `$tableRows = $this->dbTable->fetchAll($select);`
 with `$tableRows = $qry->fetchArray();`

Comment: @flammon I'm away for a 24hrs with work I'll try your suggestion when I get home. cheers mate.